# Callout via Named Credentials with client credentials oAuth flow

Tags: oauth2, namedcredentials

I'm trying to set up an external service that will rely on REST API calls **from** Salesforce **to** Marketo, which relies on [client credentials OAuth 2.0 to authenticate](https://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/authentication/). To authenticate with the Marketo API, it needs to send a client id and client secret to an identity server, which returns a temporary access token and the number of seconds until the token expires. That token can then be used to authorize subsequent callouts.
It seems that Salesforce supports this for authentication for calls **to**, but maybe not for calls **from** Salesforce?
I was planning to leverage the external service inside of a flow, with flow actions, to build things no-code or low-code. Is there a secure way to do this without writing a bunch of apex or using something like Mulesoft to handle the connection?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [External + Named Credential with oAuth client credentials flow](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/409484/external-named-credential-with-oauth-client-credentials-flow)

Answer (score 1):

As of 15 August 2023, you need to continue relying on Apex.

If you can wait and things become fruitful, this should be possible at [Winter'24](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_security_named_credentials_clientcredentials.htm&release=246&type=5) as part of the Named Credentials framework.

Comment: Good call, thought it'd be later than Winter '24.